# Python - count successive leading digits on a pandas row string without counting non successive digits

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to create a new column that counts the number of leading 0s, however I am getting errors trying to do so.
I extracted data from mongo based on the following regex `[\^0[0]*[1-9][0-9]*\]` on mongo and saved it to a csv file. This is all "Sequences" that start with a 0.

```
df['Sequence'].str.count('0')
```

and

```
df['Sequence'].str.count('0[0]*[1-9][0-9]')
```

Give the below results. As you can see that both of the "count" string return will also count non leading 0s. Or simply the total number of 0s.

```
    Sequence    0s
0   012312312   1
1   024624624   1
2   036901357   2
3   002486248   2
4   045074305   3
5   080666140   3
```

I also tried writing using loops which worked when testing but when using it on the data frame, I encounter the following `**IndexError: string index out of range**`

```
results = []
count = 0 
index = 0
for item in df['Sequence']:
    count = 0 
    index = 0
    while (item[index] == "0"):  
            count = count + 1          
            index = index + 1
    results.append(count)
df['0s'] = results
df
```

In short; If I can get 2 for 001230 substring instead of 3. I could save the results in a column to do my stats on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extract` with the `^(0*)` regex to match only the leading zeros. Then use `str.len` to get the length.

```
df['0s'] = df['sequence'].str.extract('^(0*)', expand = False).str.len()
```

Example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sequence': ['12040', '01230', '00010', '00120']})
```

Output:

```
  sequence  0s
0    12040   0
1    01230   1
2    00010   3
3    00120   2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
'^0+'
```

the `^` means, capture if the pattern starts at the beginning of the string.
the `+`means, capture if occuring at least once or multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Try `str.findall`:

```
df['0s'] = df['Sequence'].str.findall('^0*').str[0].str.len()
print(df)

# Output:
    Sequence  0s
0  012312312   1
1  024624624   1
2  036901357   1
3  002486248   2
4  045074305   1
5  080666140   1
```

Comment: The goal is to only match the leading zeros (see my answer) ;)

Comment: You are right. Thanks for your message and nice answer :)

Comment: @Corralien, thanks, it worked. I was really stuck on using .count('^0*') and never thought about str.findall(). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to count the number of leading 0s, right? Take advantage of the fact that leading 0s disappear when an integer of `type str` is converted to that of `type int`. Here's one solution:

```
df['leading 0s'] = df['Sequence'].str.len() - df['Sequence'].astype(int).astype(str).str.len()
```

Output:

```
    Sequence  leading 0s
0  012312312           1
1  024624624           1
2  036901357           1
3  002486248           2
4  045074305           1
5  080666140           1
```

Comment: This is an interesting method. However I get Python int too large to convert to C long error when using with the final data.